# Security issue about WS-Discovery protocol

Tags: web-services, security, ws-security, system-administration, ws-discovery

How comes all servers on LAN broadcsat WS-Discovery Resolve message that ends up with total congestion?

The LAN is flooded with resolve messages from different servers to IPv4 multicast address.

The following is the message body

urn:uuid:704c7c3d-b73f-410d-88bc-68d5c5dd9219

How is it all about?

Edit: It's how it works. However the point is, why they never stop? What if a resolve fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because using the WS-Discovery protocol clients send Resolve message by using UDP multicast to find out transport addresses for services. The UDP multicast is what you're seeing unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @BrandonZeider why they never stop resolving? What if resolve fails?

Comment: I don't know why they aren't resolving, that will depend on your environment (no one listening perhaps?). What happens when resolve fails, again that will be implementation specific. In my experience there is usually a timeout involved, but that may not be the case for you. What are these services built using? Java? .NET?

Comment: Ok this seems weird. Actually it's about the congestion of my dormitory network. I believe there isn't any service and they are not real servers but PCs. I sniffered and found the congestion is caused by massive WSD resolve from different clients, which I believe not working together.

Comment: I was just curious, and well someone superior in administration should solve this. Is it possibly an issue of system update?

Comment: could be I suppose...hard to tell